# link my existing instagram application with facebook application

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-graph-api

So I already have FB app and Instagram application on instagram.com. Now I want to move my instagram application under my FB application is there any option to do that?

If not, my fb app is in live mode and if I create instagram app under FB app it needs to be reviewed and for that app has to be turned to development mode which I can not do as my mobile app is in production and we have users. What should I do in this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to move the app. You will need to create a new Instagram app, and also a **test** Facebook and Instagram app. You can then submit the **live** app for review, but in the submission you can select the **test** app to be used.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps#live-mode

Comment: but my fb app is in live mode.. do I have to turn it to development mode in order to submit for review? right now under instagram app I see "no test app" to select.

Comment: You need to create the test app from your live app. Then you leave the live app in live mode, and when you submit, you choose the test app.

Comment: how do I do that?